# One-to-many table ensuring both tables are from the same parent up the chain

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-structures, relationship

I have the following tables in my Postgres 9.2 schema:

```
TABLE Root (
     RootId PRIMARY KEY,
     ...
)
```

*Note:* `...` *Means there are other columns in the table*

The `Root` has one-to-many relationships with two tables: `NodeOne` and `NodeTwo`

```
TABLE NodeOne (
    NodeOneName,
    NodeOneCode,
    RootId REFERENCES Root(RootId),
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (NodeOneName, NodeOneCode)
)

TABLE NodeTwo (
    NodeTwoName,
    NodeTwoCode,
    RootId REFERENCES Root(RootId),
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode)
)
```

`NodeTwo` has a one-to-many relationship with table `NodeTwoLeaf`

```
TABLE NodeTwoLeaf (
    NodeTwoLeafId PRIMARY KEY,
    NodeTwoName,
    NodeTwoCode,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode)
        REFERENCES NodeTwo(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode)
)
```

*Note: To know the `RootId` a given `NodeTwoLeaf` belongs to, one would have to `JOIN` back up to `NodeTwo` using the `FOREIGN KEY(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode)`.*

The problem is as follows: `NodeTwoLeaf` has a one-to-many relationship with `NodeOne`

```
NodeTwoLeaf_X_NodeOne (
    NodeTwoLeafId REFERENCES NodeTwoLeaf(NodeTwoLeafId),
    NodeOneName,
    NodeOneCode,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY (NodeTwoLeafId, NodeOneName, NodeOneCode),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(NodeOneName, NodeOneCode)
        REFERENCES NodeOne(NodeOneName, NodeOneCode)
)
```

How do I ensure in `NodeTwoLeaf_X_NodeTwo` that each `(NodeTwoLeaf, NodeOne)` pair has a common `Root` i.e. same `RootId`? (preferably using just constraints i.e. no Triggers)

Comment: @joop, there is no `NodeTwoId`. The `PK` in `NodeTwo` is made up of `NodeTwoName` and `NodeTwoCode`.

Comment: You should try to implement a tree structure using tables. That's sooo wrong.

Comment: Hey @JakubKania. Since `8.4`, Postgres can handle tree structures just fine using `WITH RECURSIVE`. Why do you say it's **sooo wrong**?

Comment: Because the nodes should be stored in rows not in seperate tables.

Comment: @JakubKania Ahh... My bad. `Root`, `NodeOne`, etc. are just names, they are not actual `tree node`s. For example, `Root` could be a `School`, `NodeOne` could be a `Course`, `NodeTwo` could be a `Qualification`, etc. I just wanted to make the question more generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a composite key.  Instead of:

```
TABLE NodeTwoLeaf (
    NodeTwoLeafId PRIMARY KEY,
    NodeTwoName,
    NodeTwoCode,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode)
        REFERENCES NodeTwo(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode)
);
```

do instead:

```
TABLE NodeTwoLeaf (
    NodeTwoLeafId PRIMARY KEY,
    RootID int,
    NodeTwoName,
    NodeTwoCode,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode, RootId)
        REFERENCES NodeTwo(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode, RootId)
);
```

Note you will have to add an additional UNIQUE index on NodeTwo for the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE NodeTwo ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(NodeTwoName, NodeTwoCode, RootId);
```

Comment: That's solves it! I'm kicking myself for not seeing it. Thanks.